# backbone js json collection result

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

So I'm still a bit of a beginner when it comes to Backbone as I was trying to play around with it today to produce some results. The issue I am coming across is being able to see the results from the json collection object. Was hoping someone could help me out a bit and point me in the right direction.

So far my set up is like so:

```
var Game = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var GameList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Game,
  url: 'link to server json object',

  parse: function(response) {
    return response;
  }
});

var GameListView = Backbone.View.extend({

  el: $('#games-list'),

  initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.collection = new GameList();
    this.collection.fetch().done(function() {
      self.render();
    });

  },
  render: function() {
    this.collection.each(function(game) {
      console.log('Game.', game);
    });
  }
});


var testApp = new GameListView();
```

This produces in the console:

```
Game. 
r {cid: "c2", attributes: Object, collection: r, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
```

I'm not sure where I am going wrong, would like to first see the json object, then be able to cycle through each item.

Comment: Are you looking for `console.log('Game.',game.toJSON());`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `toJSON()` method, this method converts the model from `Backbone` collection or model to `JSON`, for example:

```
var json = game.toJSON();
```

This method is used very often in `Backbone` development,usually for passing the model to the `html` template

Comment: How would I go about cycling through the json now and creating html elements with a value based on one of the json parameters like id or name value?

Comment: this tutorial might be useful http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/how-to-use-templates-in-backbone-js-learning-backbone-js . please accept the answer if it works as you said. @Anks